# Add a footnote on the paper title

Tags: footnotes, titles

I want to add a footnote to the title of my paper. I am able to get a asterisk appearing at the end of the title but there is no actual footnote on the bottom of the page where we normally expect footnote to be. Instead, it's still the AAAI copyright info. [image]Here I've attached a MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\frenchspacing
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\pdfinfo{
 /Title (Insert Your Title Here)
/Author (Put All Your Authors Here, Separated by Commas)}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  
\begin{document}
\title{Formatting Instructions \\for Authors Using \LaTeX{}\footnote{Example.}}
\author{AAAI Press\\
Association for the Advancement of Artificial Intelligence\\
2275 East Bayshore Road, Suite 160\\
Palo Alto, California 94303\\
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\begin{quote}
AAAI creates proceedings, working notes... 
\end{quote}
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the copyright info and just add a footnote or remove the copyright altogether? Where should the footnote go, above/below (if the copyright stays)? If this is for a journal submission, you should strongly reconsider modifications to their templates.

Comment: you might try separating the two parts as `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{...}`, the latter outside the title.

Comment: `aaai` is an obsolete LaTeX 2.09 style. Without loading it, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how.   Download [aaai](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php)http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Author/author.php

Note: Need to use `\nocopyright` before `\maketitle` and use `\thanks` for footnote.
As mentioned in the comment by @Bernard, without aaai package works fine (with different style, one column). So this solution is for if `aaai.sty` is obtained from the link mentioned above (with two column style).

[image]

Comment: Since AAAI still did not confirm if I can remove all the copyright info, I am just removing it anyway and go for this answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the following codes which is described in this webpage:

[How to Add a Footnote With No Number in LaTeX](http://code.hammerpig.com/add-footnote-number-latex.html)

```
\footnote{A footnote with numbering}

\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{A footnote without numbering}
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @Rasmus https://web.archive.org/web/20160404092219/http://code.hammerpig.com/add-footnote-number-latex.html